Why won't my 555 strobe circuit work as intended?
I made this circuit on Fusion and simulated it on Falstad.


It should be running with 12V DC (car electricity.) As you can see, everything is alright on Falstad. I constructed and tried this circuit on my car's back fog lamp. I connected everything right (Vcc to + from car, GND to - from car, and connected lamp's - to transistor's drain. I also connected lamp's + to Vcc.) When I switched on the fog lamp, it just statically lit as I didn't connect anything between the lamp and the battery. It should be strobing like on Falstad but it doesn't. It should strobe 5 times in a second and wait a while. I first thought maybe it was the bulb. Here are photos of the circuit I built:


On the second photo the terminals are from top to bottom:

Drain of the MOSFET (that is where I connected the bulb's (-))
GND of the circuit (connected it to (-) of the car battery.)
Vcc of the circuit (connected it both (+)from car and the (+) of bulb.

I connected an LED instead of the bulb but nothing changed. I am thinking maybe I miscalculated the resistor and capacitor values and it won't strobe or strobe too fast to see, but there is one thing. I set Falstad's simulation speed to match the real-world clock like 1s in simulation equals 1s in the real world. I don't know if Falstad already sets it to the real world and I changed it so my values are off than they should be. You can see how I set the Falstad on the link tho. Please help me with this. I can still change the resistors and capacitors on the circuit. If anyone could tell me what I did wrong, it would be a big help to me.
I am now thinking about replacing the 100k resistors with 47k ones and the capacitor on the same 555 with a 22uF one. I used an IRFZ44N and it seems its threshold is 10V. Although an IRLZ44N has a 5V threshold and is simply the same as an IRFZ44N. I think I should replace the MOSFETs too. What should I do? I will buy a 12V 2A adapter to test this circuit tomorrow and will try with a red LED. I guess 2A should be enough because the LED needs very little current and the original bulb I intended to use also draws 420 mA. Please instruct me if there is something wrong or right on the circuit.

You only show the Falstad simulation. There is no indication that the circuit you built is built with no errors, or wrong kind of components used incorrectly etc, too small FET that is now damaged, or simply using an 10uF electrolytic capacitor having leakage current larger than the charge current through 200k resistance. You need to do some measurements on your circuit what matches the simulation and what doesn't. 12V in a car is very noisy and spiky, you have no bypass caps or protection from damage if a spike of voltage happens to reach the chips. The simulation also wastes 9W in FET.

I used IRFZ44N as MOSFET, and unfortunately don't have the Fuison drawing anymore. I can draw it again tho. But it was showing no errors. Please inform me about bypass caps and leakage. Because I don't know about these. I added the circuit's photos on the question.

You may want to avoid the possibility of inducing an epileptic fit in the driver of the car behind you...

The light is not so bright and I am not planning to open it while in traffic so it won't be a problem. But this came in mind. I used IRFZ44N and it needs 10V of gate voltage. Maybe 555 is not enough to open the gate of MOSFET. If I replace it with a IRLZ44N, it may solve my problem?

At least you could have labeled some terminals in the photos. That's just random looking mess to anyone but you as the designer, and we are late to the party with no knowledge unless the effort taken to reverse-engineer that to find a mistake.

Your schematic does not match your constructed board. Pin-3 of your 2nd 555 is connected to a wire that goes nowhere, and the 10k which in your schematic connects from the 555 to the IRFZ44 instead connects between G and S of the MOSFET.

Thats my mistake sorry. I labeled them on a paper but forgot to add its photo. But it was in my native language so it won't be helping too. So on the second photo on right from top to bottom, first one is drain of Mosfet, second one is ground of circuit and bottom one is the Vcc.

That 10k is between G and S of the MOSFET because one of my friends suggested I need to add a bleeder resistor between G and S. It is not on the schematic sorry. And you are correct, the pin 3 is connected to nothing on this image but after I took this image I added a 220 ohm resistor between Pin 3 and G of the MOSFET. So these photos are a bit outdated yes, but the final version of circuit is like on Falstad.

I will replace the photos with recent ones when I can do, but for now, I can't leave the school for another 2 or 3 hours. I will update them when I can tho.

The capacitor at the bottom end of the first picture is soldered in reverse polarity, which causes a lot of leakage current. It will never be charged.

also there is too much excess space on your perf-board. I would recommend connecting the components on the perfboard to match your schematic, so that we can see what is wrong about your circuit.

@Jens adding on: reverse polarity on a capacitor like that destroys the capacitor

@JadonJung Yes, on the long run the capacitor will be destroyed, but through this high value charge resistor it will take some weeks.

I managed to solve it. Here is what I did:
First I reversed that capacitor that Jens mentioned. I also replaced it with a 22uF one later due to short pulses. After that I looked at the circuit more carefully and I noticed that the second 555's ground was not connected. I connected it to ground and solved this silly mistake. After that, I noticed the first 555's pin-6 has no connection to capacitor due to bad soldering. When I soldered it nice, circuit began to work.
I tested it with a red LED in series with 1K resistor and 9V battery. I also tried it with 12V regulated LED strip. These both work fine but 12V car bulb is not. Maybe it is not made to work with 9V and when I install it on the car it will work.
There is a problem still here, though.
When I  power the circuit, the first pulse of strobes is always longer than the others. Like if it is flashing 5 times in other strobes, it flashes 8 or 9 times when the power is first connected. I also still don't know how I am going to protect this circuit from inrush voltage and voltage spikes. My friend suggested that I should use a 1N4007 parallel to a resistor but I didn't understand how. Please let me know if you know how to do these.
Here is the last state of the circuit.
Terminals on right are from top to bottom for the image below;

Drain of the MOSFET
GND of the circuit
Vcc of the circuit


Terminals on right are from top to bottom for the image below;

Vcc of the circuit
GND of the circuit
Drain of the MOSFET


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Edit:
It won't work on the car.
I don't know what is the issue. It was working fine with the red LED with a 9V battery but when I connected it to my car, it just kept strobing without a waiting period. I removed the circuit with the bulb from the car. I will get myself a 12V 2A adapter and test it as it is connected to my car. But I don't know what is wrong with it. I don't know what to test it. Maybe I change the resistors and capacitors with different values. Please let me know if you think something is wrong with my setup.
I will specify the materials here for clarification;

First 555
resistors are 100k
capacitor is 22uF
Second 555
resistors are 4.7k
capacitor is 10uF
Output pin of second 555 is connected to GATE of an IRFZ44N with a 220 ohm resistor in series. The bleeder resistor between SOURCE and GATE is 10k.


I will get myself a 12V 2A adapter ... car has higher voltage when the engine is running, unless it's an electric vehicle ... get a 14 V adapter

I know cars charge at 14.4V but I don't have any access to a 14V adapter. I mean there are no 14V adapters on the market I can access.

There's a LOT of noise on a vehicle's 12V/14V DC supply, likely to cause false triggering. One thing missing from your design is supply decoupling (also know as "bypass") capacitors, which would certainly help with the false triggering, and should not be considered optional, as many people seem to think.

Just about any lab power supply will supply you 14.4 V.

unfortunately, lab power supplies are out of my price range. They are like 15x more expensive than a 12V adapter. Shitty Turkish economy :( I will add a bypass capacitor to this circuit when I got it to work. Lots of people suggested that I need to add them.
